# list empty port groups in vcenter powercli scripts

Tags: shell, virtual-machine, vmware, powercli, vcenter

Get Unused PortGroups in a Cluster or island

get a list of the vPorts used by the Vms and another list from the vPorts of the Cluster. Then i do something just like a procv in Excel and compare both lists, keeping the difference in another list, the unused PortGroup List.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.